# Accessing microphone readout for rough decibel meassurement

Tags: azure, arduino, iot-devkit, mxchip

I am new to Arduino development and just started trying some of the provided examples for the MXChip devkit. What I'm trying to do now is accessing the analog readout from the microphone to get a rough estimation of sound levels. I tried to find information on how to do this and found some articles that use an Arduino board and an external microphone wired to the analog inputs. Since the dev kit has a built-in microphone, I want to use that, but I don't know how to access it, and I can't find any information on pin layout. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microphone is not connected to the analog pins. It is connected to dedicated Audio codec hardware.

See https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/apis/audio-v2/

The hardware does not seem to give you direct access to incoming values. It looks like you will need to record and the read the buffer to get audio input levels.